# Form data not updated on live server with --prod flag

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-forms

```
<form (submit)="false"    #loginForm2="ngForm" >
  <mat-form-field  >
    <input
      #emailField="ngModel" name="emailField" email [(ngModel)]="loginData.email" matInput
      placeholder="Enter your email" required value="">
    <span matPrefix><mat-icon>email</mat-icon></span>

  </mat-form-field>

  {{loginData|json}}



</form>
```

If built with `ng serve --aot` everything works as expected.

However, if added `--prod` the loginData output is not updated when I typed.
The loginForm2 and emailField are valid objects but just the loginData not output correctly.

i have checked everywhere many times but can't find what's wrong.

No error in browser console.

using angular 5.1.3 and material 5.0.3

==============

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class AppLoginComponent {
  showPassword: boolean = false;

  loginData: any = {

  };

  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly loginService: LoginService,
  ) {
  }
  ... other code ...
}
```

Comment: can you show your component.ts code?

Comment: can you please add a small reproduction of your problem on plnkr or stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try declaring the `email` property in the `loginData` object? By the way, you don't have to add the `public` property, it should already be public in the first place! You also don't have to add the `any` type.

```ts
loginData = {
    email: ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i think it's uglify-js problem.

see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/pull/199

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8997

i upgraded the underlying uglify-es and it's all fine now.

i didn't look into detail what's the issue.